# How to resolve reduce-reduce conflict in Irony?

Tags: context-free-grammar, irony, reduce-reduce-conflict

I'm writing an extended mathematical expression evaluator. It is supposed to allow defining macros in the form:

```
f(x):=2*x
```

I'm using Irony to break the expression into the parse tree. Grammar looks like following:

```cs
using Irony.Parsing;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProCalc.NET.Grammar
{
    class MathExpressionGrammar : Irony.Parsing.Grammar
    {
        public MathExpressionGrammar()
        {
            // Construct elements

            var unaryOperator = new NonTerminal("UnaryOperator");
            var unaryOperation = new NonTerminal("UnaryOperation");
            var binaryOperator = new NonTerminal("BinaryOperator");
            var binaryOperation = new NonTerminal("BinaryOperation");
            var variable = new NonTerminal("Variable");
            var externalVariable = new NonTerminal("ExternalVariable");

            var arguments = new NonTerminal("Arguments");
            var functionCall = new NonTerminal("FunctionCall");
            var matrixEntries = new NonTerminal("MatrixEntries");
            var matrixRows = new NonTerminal("MatrixRows");
            var matrix = new NonTerminal("Matrix");
            var listEntries = new NonTerminal("ListEntries");
            var list = new NonTerminal("List");
            var term = new NonTerminal("Term");
            var scalar = new NonTerminal("Scalar");
            var parenthesis = new NonTerminal("Parenthesis");
            var expression = new NonTerminal("Expression");
            var root = new NonTerminal("Root");
            var variableAssignment = new NonTerminal("VariableAssignment");
            var functionAssignment = new NonTerminal("FunctionAssignment");
            var parameters = new NonTerminal("Parameters");
            var indexer = new NonTerminal("Indexer");
            var indices = new NonTerminal("Indices");

            var integer = new RegexBasedTerminal("Integer", "[0-9]+");
            var real = new RegexBasedTerminal("Real", @"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?e[\+\-]?[0-9]+)");
            var complex = new RegexBasedTerminal("Complex", @"(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?e[\+\-]?[0-9]+))i");
            var sysInteger = new RegexBasedTerminal("SysInteger", "0((b[0-1]+)|(o[0-7]+)|(d[0-9]+)|(h[0-9a-fA-F]+))");
            var dms = new RegexBasedTerminal("Dms", @"[0-9]+:[0-5]?[0-9](:[0-5]?[0-9](\.[0-9]+)?)?");
            var @string = new RegexBasedTerminal("String", @"""(([^""])|(""""))*""");
            var bignum = new RegexBasedTerminal("BigNum", @"[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[lL]");
            var comma = ToTerm(",", "Comma");
            var semicolon = ToTerm(";", "Semicolon");

            var identifier = new RegexBasedTerminal("Identifier", @"[a-zA-Z_@][a-zA-Z0-9\._@]*");
            var callparam = new RegexBasedTerminal("CallParam", @"_[0-9]+");
            var assign = ToTerm(":=");

            // Configure non-terminals

            root.Rule = variableAssignment | functionAssignment | expression;

            variableAssignment.Rule = identifier + assign + expression;

            functionAssignment.Rule = identifier + "(" + parameters + ")" + assign + expression;
            parameters.Rule = MakePlusRule(parameters, comma, identifier);

            expression.Rule = term | unaryOperation | binaryOperation | indexer;

            term.Rule = scalar | @string | matrix | list | functionCall | variable | callparam | externalVariable | parenthesis;
            scalar.Rule = integer | real | complex | sysInteger | dms | bignum;

            matrix.Rule = ToTerm("[") + matrixRows + "]";
            matrixRows.Rule = MakePlusRule(matrixRows, semicolon, matrixEntries);
            matrixEntries.Rule = MakePlusRule(matrixEntries, comma, term);

            list.Rule = ToTerm("{") + listEntries + "}";
            listEntries.Rule = MakePlusRule(listEntries, comma, term);

            functionCall.Rule = identifier + "(" + arguments + ")";
            arguments.Rule = MakePlusRule(arguments, comma, expression);

            variable.Rule = identifier;

            externalVariable.Rule = ToTerm("$") + identifier;

            parenthesis.Rule = ToTerm("(") + expression + ")";

            unaryOperation.Rule = unaryOperator + term + ReduceHere();
            unaryOperator.Rule = ToTerm("-") | "!";

            binaryOperation.Rule = expression + binaryOperator + expression;
            binaryOperator.Rule = ToTerm("+") | "-" | "*" | "/" | @"\" | "%" | "^" | "<<" | ">>" | "<" | ">" | "<=" | ">=" | "==" | "!=" | "&" | "|" | "#";

            indexer.Rule = term + "[" + indices + "]";
            indices.Rule = MakePlusRule(indices, comma, integer);

            // Configure operators

            RegisterOperators(50, "&", "|", "#", "<<", ">>");
            RegisterOperators(30, "^");
            RegisterOperators(20, "/", @"\", "%");
            RegisterOperators(15, "*");
            RegisterOperators(10, "+", "-");
            RegisterOperators(5, "<", ">", "<=", ">=", "==", "!=");

            // Clean up unnecessary terms

            MarkPunctuation(",", ";", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "=");

            this.Root = root;
        }
    }
}
```

Upon compiling, I'm getting exactly one reduce-reduce conflict:

```
State S66 (Inadequate)
  Reduce-reduce conflicts on inputs: ) Comma
  Shift items:
    FunctionCall -> Identifier ·( Arguments ) 
  Reduce items:
    Parameters -> Identifier · [) Comma]
    Variable -> Identifier · [[ + - * / \ % ^ << >> < > <= >= == != & | # ) Comma]
  Transitions: (->S75
```

Irony complains about the function assignment rule. And indeed, attempt to parse (perfectly valid) expression:

```
f(x)
```

yields an error (":= expected").

It is weird for me though, because without :=, it is a perfect expression:

```
Root -> 
Expression -> 
Term -> 
FunctionCall -> 
Identifier ( Arguments ) -> 
"f" ( Expression ) -> 
"f" ( Term ) -> 
"f" ( Variable ) -> 
"f" ( Identifier ) ->
"f" ( "x" )
```

I guess that ambiguity comes from the fact, that `Parameters` are actually a subset of `Arguments` - for instance "x, y, z" may be passed both inside function declaration and function invocation.

I could fix that by allowing `arguments` inside function declaration:

```cs
functionAssignment.Rule = identifier + "(" + arguments + ")" + assign + expression;
```

Then, in "runtime", I'd check, if all arguments are variables. This seems like a workaround though, because in reality there is no way you could ambiguously resolve function declaration and call (first requires :=, second forbids existence of :=).

How can I fix this reduce-reduce conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems like a workaround though, because in reality there is no way you could ambiguously resolve function declaration and call (first requires `:=`, second forbids existence of `:=`).

That's true; the grammar is not ambiguous. But unambiguous is not enough to build a parser.

The problem is that the parsing decision needs to be made before the `)` is shifted, and at that point the (possible) `:=` is not yet visible. The decision that needs to be made is precisely whether to reduce the `x` to an `expression`; that reduction would be needed if the eventual result will be a function call and incorrect if the eventual result will be a function assignment. And remember that the action needs to be decided on the basis of just one lookahead token, so the fact that the `:=` (if it exists) is two tokens a way is critical.

Indeed, the simplest solution is the one you suggest; accept `arguments` instead of `parameters` and then check in the reduction for `functionAssignment` (or earlier, if you prefer, by splitting `functionAssignment` into something like `templatePrototype + assign + expression`. It's reasonable to call that a workaround; it's a workaround for the fact that the simplest grammar is LALR(2), not LALR(1).

There are other alternatives which can produce a more precise grammar. An LALR(2) grammar can always be used to produce a (much larger) LALR(1) grammar. But the resulting grammar is much less readable (and harder to maintain), and the check in the semantic action is quite simple.

Another workaround which is sometimes recommended is to modify the lexer so that a `)` followed by `:=` produces a different token than `)` not followed by `:=`. That keeps the grammar simple, but complicates the lexer. (And remember that there might be a comment between the two tokens, so it's not just a simple regular expression.)

If you really want to see how this could be resolved, you can take a look at these answers to somewhat similar questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61397063/1566221
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70601680/1566221
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16931641/1566221

Searching on this site for `LALR(2)` will probably find more instances.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Irony has a feature, which allows inserting virtual hints into the grammar, such as `PreferShiftHere()` or `ReduceHere()`. My context-free-grammar-fu is a little bit rusty (more than a decade after my studies, sigh), but is there a chance it would help in this case?

Comment: @spook: no. You need more lookahead to make the shift/reduce decision; you can't hardwire the decision, since both possibilities could be correct  for different inputs. Sorry.